# DataGridView Show Selected Row Data In Another Form

Tags: datagridview

I have two forms. i already have some values has been displayed in datagridview in one form which is connected to a ms access database. When i click a row from the datagridview in the first from a second form would a appear on the screen and display the data in text boxes. i have Tried the following code below without any success. can someone please help. Thanks

Public Class Main_Frm

```
Private Sub TBL_TEAMSBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TBL_TEAMSBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.TBL_TEAMSBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.FootBallDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Main_Frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'FootBallDataSet.TBL_TEAMS' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.TBL_TEAMSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.FootBallDataSet.TBL_TEAMS)

End Sub

Private Sub TBL_TEAMSDataGridView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TBL_TEAMSDataGridView.Click

    If TBL_TEAMSDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count Then
        Dim Schedule_Form As New Schedule_Frm
        Schedule_Form.SelectRows = TBL_TEAMSDataGridView.SelectedRows
        Schedule_Form.ShowDialog()
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: you can try the basic one `form2.textboxname.text = this.dg.currentrow.cell[name/index].value` and so on then `form2.show()`

Comment: i have also followed this example below without any success. Please help.                    
 Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click

        Dim form As New Form2

        form.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        form.TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        form.TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        form.TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
        form.ShowDialog()

    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's "SelectRows" in your Schedule_Form, however, I'd do following in th Schedule_Form:

```
Public RID as int32

Public Sub LoadMyRecordFromDataSource()
   ' your data loading function for 1 record here, use RID as a key
End Sub
```

Then, in your main form (provided, that you can edit only 1 row at a time in the text boxes - your code above would fail in that case):

```
Private Sub TBL_TEAMSDataGridView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TBL_TEAMSDataGridView.Click

    If TBL_TEAMSDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count Then
        Dim Schedule_Form As New Schedule_Frm
        Schedule_Form.RID = TBL_TEAMSDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").value ' get your ID
        Schedule_Form.LoadMyRecordFromDataSource()  ' load your selected record
        Schedule_Form.ShowDialog()
    End If

End Sub
```